# What is another way to say "working on"?

Tags: synonyms

I don't want to repeat "working" in the following sentence:

> We are working on a working arrangement.

Answer (score 4):

A few more ideas:

- putting together

  coming up with

  setting up

  composing

  making progress on

Answer (score 4):

We are pursuing a working arrangement?

We are developing a working arrangement?

If it's a document that you're preparing, "preparing", "compiling", "creating" perhaps.

And in response to an earlier answer, please, there is *no such word* as "performant".

Answer (score 3):

We are constructing?

We are formulating?

We are writing?

We are making?

Comment: +1: Since "working arrangement" is a set phrase, it works better to replace the first *working*. (Of these options, I think *formulating* works best.)

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't bother suggesting "We are arranging a working arrangement."

Comment: @Hellion: LOL!!

Comment: Aw, I was gonna say "We are working on arranging a working arrangement".

Answer (score 1):

We are organizing employment terms.

We will be formulating an organized work plan.

We will be organizing formulated employment terms.

Answer (score 0):

If *working* means *that works*, then you can use *functioning*, *functional*, *operational*, *performant*.
If *working* means *related to work*, then you can use *job*, *service*, *task*.

Comment: The question is about *working on*, not *working*.

Comment: Truly, the question is about avoiding to repeat _working_. That can be done by finding an alternative to _working on_ or _working arrangement_.

Comment: The title of the question is about *working on* in this context, and the other answers relate to that rather than *working* .  Generally speaking these are better then most suggestions; but in this question they're misleading.

Comment: The question is not the one in the title, but the one in the question body, which in this case is _I don't want to repeat "working" in the following sentence_.